# Camel file cron scheduler issue

Tags: cron, apache-camel

I have  a file component like

```
from("file:{{inputfolder}}?noop=true&maxMessagesPerPoll=1&scheduler=qurtz2&scheduler.cron=0 0-15 * ? * MON,TUE,WED,THU,FRI").log("header.camelFileName")
```

I have multiple files in the folder and I want to read all files during the execution. But seems like only one file is picked up on every hour. Is this the expected behavior or do I need to add or remove any other options to make it work properly?

Comment: Here's your problem: `maxMessagesPerPoll=1`. Remove that to read all files, or set it to a higher value.

Comment: My entire logic turns around reading files one by one from the folder. If the files are available and scheduling is removed it, the route reads all the files one by one. I will try out after removing the  maxMessagesPerPoll  option. If I add enriching will it help to read all the files one by one?

Comment: Even if you choose to read all files they will be processed one by one. From the route's perspective it is only ever working with a single file.

Comment: Thanks @noMad17. Removing maxMessagesPerPoll=1, scheduler got picked up.